godot 3.5 android aab export failed
trying to export a godot 3.5 project as an AAB file (android), and I'm getting this error
could successfully export an apk file, but playstore requires AAB file

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':assetPackReleasePreBundleTask'.
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: game\android\build\build\intermediates\asset_pack_bundle\release\installTime


I've googled the problem and can't find any past queries with the same error. There's no problem with exporting the APK, so I'm assuming all the release keystore related things are correct.
